# jQuery 'KeyDown' Event issue - Fast Typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown

I am using jQuery keydown event to detect the keycodes which inturn helps in preventing some operations.

There is one input field with class '.donothack' like as below

```
<input name="hac" class="donothack" id="donothack" value="" />
```

And in jQuery code is mentioned like as below

```
$(".donothack").on("keydown", function(event) {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
    if(event.shiftKey && event.keyCode != 9 || event.keyCode != 9) { 
        //Stop operation
    }
}
```

> Now the problem is that when someone types too fast in this input field then Every event on browser is hanged and he has to manually kill the browser or page through Task Manager of computer.

I just then decided to `console.log` the then i found that events are increasing like anything. Counting is endless as shown in image below.
**And i do not even know that how many times i pressed the keys :(**

[image]

Kindly suggest the solution?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? The keydown event triggers on every keydown, and if you do some costly calculations on each event, it will be slow.

Comment: I am checking keycode so that event shall not fired using shift or tab key..

Comment: when user types fast then all is dead

Comment: you should check the binding of the event (`$(".donothack").on("keydown",` might be called multiple times)

Comment: $(".donothack").off().on("keydown", function(event) {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
    if(event.shiftKey && event.keyCode != 9 || event.keyCode != 9) { 
        //Stop operation
    }
}

i would prefer using a keyup

$(".donothack").off().on("keyup", function(event) {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
    if(event.shiftKey && event.keyCode != 9 || event.keyCode != 9) { 
        //Stop operation
    }
}

Comment: @Gags you only need to make sure that this code is only called once.

Comment: @miketracker solution worked for me :) Cheers

Comment: @Gags this code work but, it's ugly like you don't want to do this.. post more code then we can help you

Comment: @Hacketo .. then any alternate solution? as far as i know code is called ecerytime user presses key

Comment: @Gags atm the issue you have can't be reproduced with the code you shared, you need check your code and to not rebind the event each time the user press a key. you can see that each time you press a key, you bind x^2 listener more

Comment: But i need to check the keycode everytime user presses keys

Comment: @Gags you don't have to rebind all that stuff, it's binded as long as you don't unbind it

Comment: i will need an example with any kind of operation here.. For your knowledge, i am hiding and showing some content based on keyevents

Comment: @Gags see this jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/voa1ne3k/

Comment: It means that there can be multiple classes on page that are listening to this event? as far as i know there is only one

Comment: @Gags yes, `$(".donothack")` will find all elements with the class `donothack` and `.on` will bind an event on these elements.

Comment: instead of using class '.donothack' add an id as '#donothack' could solve most of your issue

Comment: @miketracker no ,if the code bind an event each time a key is pressed, it would result the same

Comment: @Hacketo, I am asking him to use an ID with my code llike
 
$("#donothack").off().on("keydown", function(event) { console.log(event.keyCode); if(event.shiftKey && event.keyCode != 9 || event.keyCode != 9) { //Stop operation } }

Comment: @miketracker this code is ugly, please stop, it will unbind/rebind the event each time a key is pressed, browser performance...

Comment: @Hacketo, Correct me if i am wrong but this code will unbind and rebind only if its try bound multiple time and it will not bind and rebind every time key is pressed..:)

Comment: @miketracker it's the current OP issue. Then you would not have to do `.off().on(...`

Comment: @Hacketo, totally agree..

Comment: But i have only one element with class donothack on entire project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".donothack").unbind("keydown").on("keydown", function(event) {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
    if(event.shiftKey && event.keyCode != 9 || event.keyCode != 9) { 
        //Stop operation
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, ideally should move the code out of the function which is being called multiple times.

Comment: Give an example please

Comment: @Gags Your code seems to be inside a function which is being repeatedly called. try adding a console.log before $(".donothack").on("keydown"

Comment: instead of `unbind` and then `on` you can use  [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: .one() will trigger the event only once. We don't know when the handler is added again. so it should continue to trigger the event until it's removed/added again.